# Why String + CharSequence is successful?

Tags: android, tostring, gettext

```
String s = txtShow.getText().toString();
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(v.getId);
txtShow.setText(s+btn.getText());
```

The third line in above code.I find that two different datatypes are added together,that is,String + CharSequence.I run my program,there are no error.Why?

I think the third line should be

```
txtShow.setText(s+btn.getText().toString());
```

isn't? What is the difference?

Comment: btn.getText() return is CharSequence, not Editable

Answer (score 2):

Like the comment of @Euporie sad the return type of [getText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) is `CharSequence`

The concatenation with the `plus` operator are converted to the `StringBuilder` usage. 
`StringBuilder`s [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) method accept a Parameter of Type `CharSequence` thats why no error
appears.

[Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) implements the `CharSequence` interface and it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

First Off all as said by   **@Euporie**
`btn.getText()` return `CharSequence`

And for your Information `Editable` and `String` both implements [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)